# How to apply filter at runtime in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: ssrs

In my report in SSRS 2008 I have created a expression for the `CasesShipped` column like this:

```
=IIF(Fields!Current_Product.Value= "Match"," ",Sum(Fields!Cases_Shipped.Value))
```

It sums the `Cases_Shipped` value having same distributor item code. Now I want to apply  a filter for the `Cases_Shipped` drop down list value to report records after previously mentioned activity.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way would be to use a drill through report. Add an action to the row group that links to a new report. Duplicate the layout of the new report, but implement a filter on the dataset of interest.

Pass the row group value (`[SQLFieldName]`) to a parameter of the report. If you use a multivalue variable with an `IN` statement in the SQL, several filters can be used at once.